# ImageMagick .net c# mp4/webm video getting N frame without artifacts?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, imagemagick.net

Trying to make some manipulation with frames using ImageMagick lib on .net (resizing + composing with other image), but faced with incorrect "re-assembling" video, output video coming with some artifacts.

So, as a sample of mp4 short file we have :
mp4 (130kb) : https://c2n.me/4eU1Twz.mp4

first frame is : [image]
second frame is : [image]

and all next frames with similar artifacts.

Code to get frames and save them to disk :

```
string incomingFilePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "test.mp4";                   

using (var videoFrames = new MagickImageCollection(incomingFilePath, MagickFormat.Mp4))
{                        
        for (var i = 0; i < _incomingImageFrames.Count; i++)
        {
            _incomingImageFrames[i].Write(AppContext.BaseDirectory + Guid.NewGuid() + ".png");
        }
}
```

In case i am trying to "re-assemble" images to mp4 (with some modifications, using composing() method and etc), i am getting video with artifacts. Sample from output .mp4 :

So need to fix it somehow, but not sure why. Can anyone help me with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in "nature" of mp4/h.264 codec. First frame is always "full" and all others - are the difference between current and previous frame, so as i understand, when mp4 is trying "assemble" not original images (modified) - ffmpeg trying to do the best and glue them all to video.

So as a workaround - **we can just remove this frame difference at runtime** before forwarding them to ffmpeg engine.

In case of ImageMagick, we need to **compose current frame with previous** to obtain "full drew frame" as a result before assembling.

Sample code :

```
string incomingFilePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "test.mp4";                   
    
    using (var videoFrames = new MagickImageCollection(incomingFilePath, MagickFormat.Mp4))
    {
            var _resultImageCollection = new MagickImageCollection(); //temp collection
            var prevFullFrame = _incomingImageFrames.First(); //save last full frame, as initial it will be first in collection
            for (var i = 0; i < _incomingImageFrames.Count; i++)
            {
                prevFullFrame.Composite(_incomingImageFrames[i],_incomingImageFrames[i].Page.X, _incomingImageFrames[i].Page.Y, CompositeOperator.Over); //combining previous (full frame) with current (with partial filled pixels)
                _resultImageCollection.add(prevFullFrame); //adding to result collection
            }
            _resultImageCollection.Write(AppContext.BaseDirectory + "result.mp4"); //assembling mp4
    }
```

Maybe not the best from performance side, but it works fine. Also, it will some increase size, but not dramatically. In my case it was about +10%, so acceptable. (36Kb vs 40Kb)

**Update : it will have the same size if you will call Optimize() for collection** before save.

```
_resultImageCollection.Optimize();
```

Maybe anyone know better solution?